# Adding x no of days to given date, but it is taking the day number as month and doing the calc. Help me fix the format

Tags: php

I m trying to add 28 days to the given date and echo, however it is taking the given date and considering it as month and adding the days given

Help me fix the format.

my code goes as:

```
$start = "04/03/2019";


$nextpay1 = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($start . "+28 days"));

echo $nextpay1;
```

as result it is echoing "01/05/2019", which is not right..

Comment: @ccKep will it get resolved if i kept in a hosting that is from US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start my answer by quoting the [strtotime docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: **if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed**; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So, in your case:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '04/03/2019');
$date->modify('+28 days');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: can i echo a variable in place of the date '04/03/2019'...?

Comment: echo? I don't know what you mean, but you can use a variable as the 2nd parameter to `DateTime::createFromFormat` ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$start` is being parsed in the default `mm/dd/yyyy` format. You should use a function to parse it as the format you intend, and then add to that.

```
$parsed = date_parse_from_format('d/m/Y', $start);
$startdate = mktime(
    $parsed['hour'], 
    $parsed['minute'], 
    $parsed['second'], 
    $parsed['month'], 
    $parsed['day'], 
    $parsed['year']
);
$nextpay1 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+28 days', $startdate));
```

Comment: `date_parse_from_format` returns an array, `strtotime` expects an `int` as it's 2nd parameter.

Comment: Fixed, I added a call to convert the array to a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date=Date('y:m:d', strtotime("+3 days"));
```

This will save the date after 3 days

Comment: But i need the final result to be in d/m/Y format only

Comment: And the $start value date vary .. it wont be today date